# Does $4x^2+1=5^y$ have a solution in integers with $y>1$?

Tags: diophantine-equations

Consider the following equation :

> $4x^2+1=5^y~$ with $y>1$

Has this equation solutions in integers ?

I wrote small Maple program in order to find solutions but couldn't find anyone .

```
for x from 1 to 6000 do
for y from 2 to 2000 do
if 4*x^2+1 = 5^y then
print(x,y);
end if;
end do;
end do;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not according to [Catalan's conjecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan%27s_conjecture) (actually a theorem), since you have $5^y-(2x)^2=1$.